# Why might 'mpstat' and 'pidstat' disagree about CPU load levels?

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage

I'm monitoring a mysql process in ubuntu 12.04 using `mpstat` and `pidstat`, simultaneously. While debugging its CPU usage, I noticed something unusual. While both tools agree that CPU load is occurring, they *disagree* about what kind of load it is. Here's an exemplar time slice:

```
$ pidstat -p 2763 1
01:36:36 PM       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
01:36:36 PM      2763    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0  mysqld
01:36:37 PM      2763    0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00     0  mysqld
01:36:38 PM      2763    0.00    5.00    0.00    5.00     0  mysqld
01:36:39 PM      2763    0.00   11.00    0.00   11.00     0  mysqld
01:36:40 PM      2763    0.00   12.00    0.00   12.00     0  mysqld
01:36:41 PM      2763    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0  mysqld
01:36:42 PM      2763    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0  mysqld
01:36:43 PM      2763    0.00    5.00    0.00    5.00     0  mysqld
01:36:44 PM      2763    0.00  170.00    0.00  170.00     0  mysqld
01:36:45 PM      2763    0.00  150.00    0.00  150.00     0  mysqld
01:36:46 PM      2763    0.00    4.00    0.00    4.00     0  mysqld
01:36:47 PM      2763    0.00    7.00    0.00    7.00     0  mysqld
01:36:48 PM      2763    0.00    7.00    0.00    7.00     0  mysqld
01:36:49 PM      2763    0.00   59.00    0.00   59.00     0  mysqld
01:36:50 PM      2763    0.00   85.00    0.00   85.00     0  mysqld
```

Note that `pidstat` is reporting heavy system-level usage at various points in time. Here's `mpstat` for roughly the same time period:

```
$ mpstat -P ALL 1
01:36:37 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:38 PM  all    0.38    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.62
01:36:38 PM    0    2.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.98
01:36:38 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:38 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:38 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:38 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:38 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:38 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:38 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:38 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:39 PM  all    0.88    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.12
01:36:39 PM    0    4.08    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.92
01:36:39 PM    1    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
01:36:39 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:39 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:39 PM    4    0.99    0.00    0.99    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.02
01:36:39 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:39 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:39 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:39 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:40 PM  all    0.62    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.38
01:36:40 PM    0    5.05    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.95
01:36:40 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:40 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:40 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:40 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:40 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:40 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:40 PM    7    0.99    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.01

01:36:40 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:41 PM  all    1.25    0.00    0.25    0.00    0.00    0.12    0.00    0.00   98.38
01:36:41 PM    0   10.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00   88.00
01:36:41 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:41 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:41 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:41 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:41 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:41 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:41 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:41 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:42 PM  all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:42 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:42 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:43 PM  all    0.12    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.88
01:36:43 PM    0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:43 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:43 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:43 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:43 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:43 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:43 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:43 PM    7    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.00

01:36:43 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:44 PM  all    2.88    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.12
01:36:44 PM    0   22.77    0.00    0.99    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   76.24
01:36:44 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:44 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:44 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:44 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:44 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:44 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:44 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:44 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:45 PM  all   23.72    0.00    0.12    0.00    0.00    0.12    0.00    0.00   76.03
01:36:45 PM    0   99.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
01:36:45 PM    1   89.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   11.00
01:36:45 PM    2    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.00
01:36:45 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.99    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.01
01:36:45 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:45 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:45 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:45 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:45 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:46 PM  all   13.89    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.13    0.00   85.98
01:36:46 PM    0   34.34    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.01    0.00    0.00   64.65
01:36:46 PM    1   69.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   31.00
01:36:46 PM    2    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.00
01:36:46 PM    3    3.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.00
01:36:46 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:46 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:46 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:46 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:46 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:47 PM  all    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.13    0.00    0.00   99.37
01:36:47 PM    0    3.96    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.04
01:36:47 PM    1    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.00
01:36:47 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:47 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:47 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:47 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:47 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:47 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

01:36:47 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
01:36:48 PM  all    0.63    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.37
01:36:48 PM    0    5.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.90
01:36:48 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:48 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:48 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:48 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:48 PM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:48 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
01:36:48 PM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
```

I'm not surprised to see them disagree about overall percentages, but what I can't figure out is why `pidstat` and `mpstat` disagree about the type of CPU load. `mpstat` indicates the load is happening at the application level. `pidstat` indicates it's happening at the kernel level. What's happening here? I assumed both were views into `/proc`, but I'm not versed enough in their internals to know where they're getting different signals.

EDIT: Best I can tell this results from discrepancies between the `/proc` calculation mechanism used by each program.

`pidstat` is using `/proc/<pid>/stat`: https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/pidstat.c#L373-L382

`mpstat` is using `/proc/uptime` and `/proc/stat`: https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/rd_stats.c#L59-L163

Comment: My initial suspicion is to do with the granularity of the sampling. What happens if you set the interval to 10 seconds?

Comment: @MatthewIfe -- no dice. They still more or less agree about the total load, but pidstat is still showing all load as system, while mpstat shows it as usr.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've got a cause, but it's not really a root cause:

`mpstat` relies on `/proc/stat` for its cpu metrics. `pidstat` relies on `/proc/<pid>/stat`. These files at times disagree about the number of kernel jiffies observed in a particular length of time, which I suppose makes sense as we're talking about such a increments of time resolution:

```
17:06:41 /proc/stat 158257197
17:06:46 /proc/stat 158257230
17:06:51 /proc/stat 158257236
17:06:56 /proc/stat 158257279
# t3 - t0 = 82 jiffies
```

versus...

```
17:06:41 /proc/2763/stat 208862696
17:06:46 /proc/2763/stat 208862971
17:06:51 /proc/2763/stat 208863114
17:06:56 /proc/2763/stat 208863143
# t3 - t0 = 447 jiffies
```

Each difference is, of course, subject to derivative calculation depending on `mpstat` and `pidstat`'s source code, massaging into percentages, etc.

If you dig further into `/proc` and sum `/proc/<pid>/task/**/stat`, the result makes more sense. That number grows more slowly than `/proc/stat` as a whole, and significantly more slowly than `/proc/<pid>/stat`.

It seems like if I'm going to take this any further I'd need to better understand how the kernel is writing these files, for my particular version. It's clear that `/proc/<pid>/stat` does not agree with `/proc/<pid>/task/**/stat`.

Comment: So, I looked at it too. I believe that if what you are getting is a cumalative task total in that stat output (it includes the threads under mysql). If you run the same pidstat getting thread stats do these make more marginal sense?

Comment: @MatthewIfe -- yeah, it does. Modified the answer w/ some more information.